# How to add a custom icon with specific functionality in SPYDER

Tags: editor, spyder

How to add a custom icon in the SPYDER, using which need to perform custom action.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is not possible right now, unless you modify Spyder source code and distribute those changes yourself.

However, we're working to allow this in our next major version, i.e. Spyder **4**.